# magento2.3 porto checkout error any idea why my magento will not check out

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, porto-theme

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}styles.css" />
<script>var eu_check = "yes";var redirect_eu = "";var redirect_url = "";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//disablewintracking.com/app/show.js?id=145" data-name="gdpr_include"></script><div class="gdpr_holder"></div>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-132931861-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-132931861-1');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://secure.trust-provider.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
//]]>
</script>
```